# How can I change the height and width of slideshow in NEAT theme?

Tags: themes, slideshow, neat, bigcartel

The words on my pictures in my slideshow on my [home page](http://www.angelinasfashion.com) are being cut off. How do I change the width and height so that you can see the entire picture in the slideshow?

Comment: check my website to see what i am talking about www.angelinasfashion.com

Comment: The intended behavior of the slideshow images is to scale based on the height and width of your browser window - you can see this in action if you resize the window and make it smaller/larger. So you may want to put your important text more toward the center of the image (to avoid clipping), or use a different theme that offers a different type of slideshow functionality, like Luna, Nova, Good Vibes, etc.